# What is the backstory of this building in Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

The very first scene in Ant-Man

> is set in some sort of S.H.I.E.L.D. building. The first image of the movie is a dramatic presentation of the building that seems clearly to be under construction. We might imagine that completion of the building might be tied to the upcoming plot. ... But then we never see that building in the rest of the movie.

I imagine that completion of the building is part of some other plot line somewhere else in the MCU.  So what is the building, and what is its story?

Comment: wasn't it just the triskellion (seen in CA:TWS)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The building we see during the first scene is [The Triskelion](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Triskelion) under some amount of construction.

[image: triskelion under construction]

The Triskelion is the base of operations for SHIELD seen in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*. It is where Director Fury and Alexander Pierce both have their offices, and is where SHIELD seems to do at least some major research and development ([Project Insight](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Project_Insight) is built and launched there).

[image: triskelion completed]

Comment: I think the Triskelion is damaged during season 1 of Agents of SHIELD, so that would explain its reconstruction here.

Comment: @Gaurav The first scene is set in the 1980s, so this would probably be it's original construction.

Comment: Ah, oops! Thanks for the correction! It doesn't look like I can edit my comment so I will leave it to embarrass me for years to come.

Comment: @Gaurav if you hover over to the right of your comment, you should be able to delete it if you really want to.